# Install on ios device failed with traceback error when using 3rd party module in appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator

"install on ios device" is working fine for my other projects. But in this project its failing with traceback error.

> [ERROR]  [ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Application
>   Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.8.2/iphone/builder.py", line 1440, in
>   main
>       execute_xcode("iphoneos%s" % iphone_version,args,False)   File "/Library/Application
>   Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.8.2/iphone/builder.py", line 1200, in
>   execute_xcode
>       output = run.run(args,False,False,o)   File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.8.2/iphone/run.py", line 39, in run
>       sys.exit(rc) SystemExit: 1

i am using AGCalendar 3rd party ios module.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in the newest version, so go ahead and download it from github if you haven't already.